# rules of operator's $ usage in haskell

Tags: haskell, operator-precedence

I tried the `$` operator and came to a weird point where I don't understand what is happening.

```
f = double $ 3+4
```

but this does not

```
f xs = xs !! $ length xs - 1
```

Can the operator `$` only appear after function names and not after operators? 
If so is there a way to write the following function without the parenthesis

```
f xs = xs !! (length xs - 1)
```

Comment: Note that using `!!` is always suboptimal, in particular it's bad to traverse a list twice (first to calculate the length, then to access the last element). In this example, you should obviously just use [`last` from the prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:last)! ...But I suppose this was just an example anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two operators next to each other, it's invalid syntax.  This holds true for all operators.  So `xs !! $ length xs - 1` just will not work.  There isn't really a good way to get rid of the parens in that statement without resorting to some tricks that aren't worth it and make the code less readable.

---

The `$` operator does not have to appear after function names, though, you can do

```
> let add x y = x + y
> add 1 $ add 2 $ add 3 4
```

Comment: Tiny quibble: It is not quite true for unary minus, which can appear after lower precedence operators.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Good catch!  Something like `add 1 $ -1` certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell infix notation is problematic, avoid it like this

```
f xs = (!!) xs $ length xs - 1
```

The brackets turn an infix operator into a prefix function.

Comment: `f xs = xs !! (length xs - 1)` is much more idiomatic. Either that or `f xs = (xs !!) $ length xs - 1`

Comment: @Kata I agree, but the OP wanted a simple way to do it with the `$`; this seemed like it fit the bill better.

Comment: f xs = (!!) xs $ length xs - 1
very nice!

Comment: @tomas You could also do `(!!) xs . pred . length $ xs`

Comment: and now just for curiosity:
`initmy xs = take (length xs - 1)  xs`
Is there a way to write this without parenthesis?

Comment: @tomas `initmy xs = flip take xs $ length xs - 1` is one alternative. Another is `initmy = flip take <*> pred . length` using the `ap` operator (`<*>`) from `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: `initmy xs = flip take xs $ length xs - 1` wow I imagined this way and  here it the function flip that does. :D nice! thanks